# Filter array of multiple value

Tags: javascript

This is my issue, I try to get result of items base on my filter array.

```
const papaFilter=[
{type:'event', value: ['In Person']},
{type:'city', value: ['Boston', 'Miami', 'New York']}
]

const items = [
{city: 'Boston', type: 'In Person'},
{city: 'New Jersey', type: 'In Person'},
{city:'Boston', type:'Virtual'}
]

const filteredResults = items.filter(el => papaFilter.some(filterEl => el[filterEl.type] === filterEl.value));
```

I want the first object of my items because papafilter contain Boston and In Person.

I know in my condition filterEl.value is an array of multiple value so this condition doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: because the papaFilter contain 'In Person' and 'Boston' so it match with my first object of items.

Comment: why do you have `type` in items, if you better take `event` for it? it would make the search easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the array checking all `filter` item.

This approach takes an object for replacing keys.

```js
const
    replacements = { event: 'type' },
    filter = [{ type: 'event', value: ['In Person'] }, { type: 'city', value: ['Boston', 'Miami', 'New York'] }],
    items = [{ city: 'Boston', type: 'In Person' }, { city: 'New Jersey', type: 'In Person' }, { city: 'Boston', type: 'Virtual' }],
    result = items.filter(o =>
        filter.every(({ type, value }) => value.includes(o[(replacements[type] || type)]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are a killer ! thank you

Comment: How this function can return a result if i have more key and value on my events?      
 `const filter = [
      { type: 'type', value: ['In Person', 'Virtual'] },
      { type: 'city', value: ['Boston', 'Miami', 'New York'] },
    ]
    const events = [
      { node: { city: 'Boston', type: 'In Person', name: 'Boston Party' } },
      { node: { city: 'New Jersey', type: 'In Person', name: 'Hello Cookie' } },
      { node: { city: 'Boston', type: 'Virtual', name: 'Sales Kick Off' } },
    ]`

Comment: function `const result = events.filter(o => Object.entries(o.node).every(([k, v]) => filter.some(({ type, value }) => type === k && value.includes(v)),),)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Array.includes`. So, `filterEl.value.includes(el[filterEl.type])` in the last block should give you the desired result.

You can find more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: this code ```const filteredResults = card.filter(el =>
      Filter.some(filterEl => filterEl.value.includes(el[filterEl.type])),
    )```  give me the 1 and 3 objects. I just want the first object of my items because papaFilter contain 'In Person' and 'Boston' so it match with my first object of items.

Comment: In that case, some on `papaFilter` won't help you, you need to iterate through all entries in the filter method of `items` and then return `true` only when all entries from `papaFilter`'s  iteration gives value `true`.

Also, I think `type:"event"` should be `type:"type"`.