# filter array based on multiple condition

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the result of my event based on the filter.

```js
const filter = [
  { type: 'type', value: ['In Person'] },
  { type: 'city', value: ['Boston', 'Miami', 'New York'] },
];

const events = [
  { node: { city: 'Boston', type: 'In Person', name: 'Boston Party' } },
  { node: { city: 'New Jersey', type: 'In Person', name: 'Hello Cookie' } },
  { node: { city: 'Boston', type: 'Virtual', name: 'Sales Kick Off' } },
];

const result = events.filter(o => Object
  .entries(o.node)
  .every(([k, v]) => filter
    .some(({ type, value }) => type === k && value.includes(v)),),)

console.log(result)
```

I want the first object of my events because filter contain Boston and In Person. (This function will work if I remove the key name on my events). How this function can return a result if i have more key and value on my events.

Comment: What's with the `),),)`

Comment: close parentheses for method filter , every , some. Copy past the code on your code editor and you will see better. the format on stackOverflow is not the best...

Comment: @Florian Lahitte, your commas should separate the arguments, but you have no further arguments.

Comment: the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687135/1447675) does not have commas ...

Comment: Well you are using `every` on your events, but the `name` key is nowhere to be found in your filters.

Answer (score 3):

You could filter with `filter`.

```js
const
    filter = [{ type: 'type', value: ['In Person', 'Virtual'] }, { type: 'city', value: ['Boston', 'Miami', 'New York'] }],
    events = [{ node: { city: 'Boston', type: 'In Person', name: 'Boston Party' } }, { node: { city: 'New Jersey', type: 'In Person', name: 'Hello Cookie' } }, { node: { city: 'Boston', type: 'Virtual', name: 'Sales Kick Off' } }],
    result = events.filter(({ node }) =>
        filter.every(({ type, value }) => !value.length || value.includes(node[type]))
    );

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you   again Nina Scholz.

Comment: it matches. why shouldn't be included?

Comment: sorry for my previews msg. but if you remove all value`{ type: 'type', value: [] }`. it show me nothing but the second filter show me as value Boston so it should show me 2 events.

Comment: why not remove empty filters?

Comment: Correct. Thank you again Nina Scholz.

Comment: hello @NinaScholz i have the same request but this time with multiple value on my obj do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134205/filter-array-based-on-array-of-multiple-condition